# Filling up a circle progress bar

Tags: css, css-shapes

I've search this website with multiple progressive circle sample but did not find similar to my requirement.

I'm trying to create progress circle filled from bottom to top. The % percent  value will pass from textbox.

[image: round progressive bar filling up]

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I'd try to create one black rectangle as a background, one orange rectangle as a loadbar and one grey object which will create the impression of a circle. Then I'd use JavaScript to change the size of the orange part to make it "grow" during loading.

Comment: @BenM I'm using the sample here http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-different-shapes-in-css but the progress / grow effect just killing me.

Comment: @MartinBeseda agree with the concept. But the "growing" effect is the issue how to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could handle the animation with transforms and transitions : (Hover the circle)

```css
#count{
    position:relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:200px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
}
#count span{
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background: red;
    z-index:-1;
    transform:scaleY(0.001);
    transition:transform 3s;
    transform-origin:50% 100%;
}
#count:hover span{
    transform:scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="count">100%<span></span></div>
```

Comment: Why not translateY from 100% to 0?

Comment: Its a starter with pure css, thanks BenM!

Comment: Works great in all modern browser.

Comment: Was updating scaleY value through jquery but its not getting there.


    $("#div").after(   function(){
        $("#div").animate({ transform: 'scaleY(.5)' });
    } );

Comment: @r2c3 manipulating pseudo  elements with JS isn't easy. You should use a child element for the red fill. (I have updated the answer accordingly) and don't forget the vendor prefixes for the transforms to maximize browser support.

Comment: @jbutler483 translating or scaling would have the same effect but Some older browsers have issues with overflowing transformed elements.

Comment: @web-tiki almost perfect with the option to transform the span. One thing is missing though, the overflow: hidden is not working in Safari. I tried with all vendor prefixes without luck,

http://i58.tinypic.com/2922zh3.gif

Comment: @r2c3 it is a [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98538). A workaround would be to animate with height rather than transforms : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/farbzy2o/

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the orange "growing" part like this:

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1kj5yb8/2/)**

#### JavaScript

The point here is simply resizing the orange rectangle.

```
function resize(i) {
    console.log(i);
    jQuery('#loadRec').height(i%100);
    i++;
}
```

Black background and white foreground will be static individual shapes.

Comment: Interesting and SVG's just hit my head! The idea of combining js is just what I needed. 


Slightly different though with circle with background.


Thanks @MartinBeseda.

Comment: IE has issue with .height. Any workaround?

Comment: Try `.innerHeight()` and `.outerHeight()`.