# How to color only 10% bottom of a circle using css?

Tags: jquery, css

how to color the only 10% bottom of a circle using css ?
[image]

Comment: Do you specify dimensions for the circle?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: if i said circle what is the dimesions means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138369/filling-up-a-circle-progress-bar (it actually does more than what is asked here).

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is to use box shadow for the second border and an absolutely positioned element for the 10% fill.

here's Snippet Example:

```css
  .circle {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 10px solid white;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 250px;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 3px;
      position: relative;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px gray;
      margin: 50px
    }

    .fill {
      background-color: teal;
      height: 10%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span class="text">text</span>
  <div class="fill"></div>
</div>
```

and a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ryjh4xd/2/

Comment: Nice, simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.circle-border{
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 8px solid #E6E6E6;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
  }
  .text{
   position: relative; 
   top: 15%;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #666;
   font-family: Arial;
  }
  .semi-circle{
   position: relative;
   top:25%;
      background-color: #00C0A4;
      width: 200px;
      height: 70px;
      border-radius: 50% / 100%;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="circle-border">
  <div class="text">
    <p>&#8377 1500 to &#8377 10000</p>
    <p>used this month</p>
  </div>
  <div class="semi-circle"></div>
</div>
```

I have placed a semi-circle inside a circle. Here's my solution.

```
<style>
    .circle-border{
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 8px solid #E6E6E6;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .text{
        position: relative; 
        top: 15%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #666;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    .semi-circle{
        position: relative;
        top:25%;
        background-color: #00C0A4;
        width: 200px;
        height: 70px;
        border-radius: 50% / 100%;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
</style> 

<div class="circle-border">
    <div class="text">
        <p>&#8377 1500 to &#8377 10000</p>
        <p>used this month</p>
    </div>
    <div class="semi-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inner and outer circles with `overflow: hidden`. Place some other element as *partial-color*

```css
.circle {
  width: 102px;
  height: 102px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
  }
.circle-inner {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.circle-inner:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #00aa00;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle-inner">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made using pseudo elements. If the fill colour is static this will work.

```css
.circle{
  border:3px solid #dfdfdf;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden
}
.circle:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  bottom:0;
  height:20%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:#19af5c;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Weber created this [awesome solution](http://codepen.io/kevinweber/pen/QwgKMX/) (that actually does more than asked)

```js
function animate( $that, percentage ) {
  if ( !$that.hasClass('fill') ) return;
  $that.removeClass('fill');

  percentage = (100 - percentage) || 0;
  var percentage_initial = 100,
      percentage_current = percentage_initial,
      interval = 0.5;

  var interval_gradient = setInterval(function(){
    $that.css(
      'background',
      'linear-gradient(#a0c884 '+percentage_current+'%,#426e1f '+percentage_current+'%)'
    );
    percentage_current -= interval;
    if(percentage_current <= percentage) clearInterval(interval_gradient);
  }, 5);

  $that.addClass('filled');
};

$('.fill').on('click', function() {
  var $that = $(this);
  var percentage = $that.attr('data-fill');
  setTimeout(function(){
    animate( $that, percentage )
  }, 400);
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #222;
}
.circle {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 7px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #a0c884;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.7);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.circle-text {
  font-size: 56px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-family: "Montserrat","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

/* For illustration, no effect on click */
.example {
   background: linear-gradient(#a0c884 34%, #426e1f 34%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="color:#fff;">Click:</p>

<!-- Fillable bubble -->
<div class="circle fill" data-fill="64">
    <p class="circle-text">64%</p>
</div>
<!-- / Fillable bubble -->

<p style="color:#fff;">Result:</p>
<div class="circle filled example" data-fill="64">
    <p class="circle-text">64%</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#grad1 {
    border-radius:50%;
    height: 100px;
width:100px;
   background: rgba(235,224,223,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(235,224,223,1) 0%, rgba(235,224,223,1) 90%, rgba(9,179,165,1) 90%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(235,224,223,1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(235,224,223,1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(9,179,165,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(235,224,223,1) 0%, rgba(235,224,223,1) 90%, rgba(9,179,165,1) 90%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(235,224,223,1) 0%, rgba(235,224,223,1) 90%, rgba(9,179,165,1) 90%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(235,224,223,1) 0%, rgba(235,224,223,1) 90%, rgba(9,179,165,1) 90%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(235,224,223,1) 0%, rgba(235,224,223,1) 90%, rgba(9,179,165,1) 90%);

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="grad1"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it using SVG. It would be much simpler and easier:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="200">
  <linearGradient id="lg" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="royalblue"/>
      <stop offset="20%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="royalblue"/>
      <stop offset="20%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="royalblue"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="royalblue"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="url(#lg)" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

Just change the offset where in 2nd and 4th lines where it is 20% to adjust the required percentage.